# How to get how long a user has been active , Laravel

Tags: laravel, security

In the logs section, I want it to be recorded when the user logs in that I have done this, and when he logs out, I want it to be recorded that I have done this as follows.

But when the user does not click on exit (for example, the session time is over or he closes the browser and exits his account), I want the log to record how the user's session ended? Did he leave by himself? Has its session ended and the system kicked it out?

My Laravel is 9.52

EventServiceProvider:

```
  public function boot()
    {
        Event::listen(\Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout::class, function ($event) {
//            \Log::info("User logout: {$event->user->name}");
            if(Auth::check())
            {
                Activity::create([
                    'log_name' => 'route',
                    'description' => 'Logout',
                    'causer_id' => Auth::id(),
 
                ]);
            }
 
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a new middleware for session activity tracking:
Create a new middleware class that will be responsible for tracking user session activities and handling session timeouts.

Create a file named TrackSessionActivity.php in the app/Http/Middleware directory

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class TrackSessionActivity
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Session::has('last_activity')) {
            Session::put('last_activity', now());
        } else {
            $lastActivity = Session::get('last_activity');
            $idleTime = now()->diffInMinutes($lastActivity);

            if ($idleTime >= config('session.timeout')) {
                // Log session expiry or user's inactivity
                \Log::info("User session expired or inactive: " . (Auth::user() ? Auth::user()->name : 'Guest'));
            }
        }

        // Update last activity timestamp
        Session::put('last_activity', now());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Update the Kernel to apply the middleware:
Open app/Http/Kernel.php and add 'track.session.activity' to the web middleware group:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ... other middleware entries
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrackSessionActivity::class,
    ],
];
```

Create a file named LoginListener.php in the app/Listeners directory

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LoginListener
{
    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        Log::info("User login: {$event->user->name}");
    }
}
```

Open app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php and add the LoginListener to the $listen array:

```
protected $listen = [
    Login::class => [
        \App\Listeners\LoginListener::class,
    ],
];
```

In the same EventServiceProvider, add your existing Logout event listener code:

```
protected $listen = [
    Login::class => [
        \App\Listeners\LoginListener::class,
    ],
    \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout::class => [
        function ($event) {
            if (Auth::check()) {
                \Log::info("User logout: " . Auth::user()->name);
            }
        },
    ],
];
```

In your config/session.php configuration file, you can define the session timeout duration:

```
'timeout' => env('SESSION_TIMEOUT', 30), // minutes
```

Comment: Constant expression contains invalid operations => EventServiceProvider.php

Comment: app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php

```
protected $listen = [
    \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login::class => [
        \App\Listeners\LoginListener::class,
    ],
    \Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout::class => [
        \App\Listeners\LogoutListener::class,
    ],
];
```

Comment: NOw check change these things

Comment: Clicking Logout gives an error:
Target class [App\Listeners\LogoutListener] does not exist.

Also, when the user closes the browser, the session ends, but the log is not recorded.

Comment: Create the file inside the app/Listeners .

file name  - LogoutListener.php

and put this code

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class LogoutListener
{
    public function handle(Logout $event)
    {
        Log::info("User logout: {$event->user->name}");
    }
}

Comment: now check with these changes

Comment: The error problem is solved.
But I want the log to be done when the user closes the browser or the session times out.
In the current mode, when the user logs out (Route Logout is executed), the log is saved.

Comment: When user closed the browser you can use the beforeunload method on the client side and excute the logout api.

Comment: Unfortunately, my first problem was not solved

Comment: OK let me check any another solution for the first point